How to disable the hidden lines feature in gitlens/vscode?
This feature is very annoying to me when I am going through the file history and looking for a keyword throughout.
Is there a way to disable this ?

Sorry, I can't find the correct keywords / settings for this.
I want to see all the line in the files diff. Instead of just the changed lines.

It's not a gitlens feature. It's a VS Code feature. The setting you want is diffEditor.hideUnchangedRegions.enabled (set to false).
